# Publish Feed To Facebook Jams Up PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the php SDK for the Graph API, and everything is working fine-getting usernames, uploading photos etc. 
However, when I'm trying to publish to the current user's feed, it just makes the page get stuck.

This is the code:

```
$publish_feed = $facebook->api('/'.$userid'/feed', 'post', array(
    'message'=> 'message', 
    'picture'=> 'http://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/photo.jpg', 
    'link'=> 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname/' 
););
```

I've tried:

1. Putting the code in different places in the code-no matter where I do, it gets the page stuck, Even if ti is at the end of the code, it gets it stuck, and nothing shows.
2. changing `$userid` to `/me`. No success.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the `publish_stream` permission
2. use `/me` or `api("/$userid/feed",..etc`
3. Remove the extra column:

Code:

```
$params =   array(
                'message' => 'message',
                'picture'=> 'http://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/photo.jpg',
                'link'=> 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname/'
            );
$publish_feed = $facebook->api("/$userid/feed", "post", $params);
```

Comment: don't you want to append the variable? `.$userid.`

Comment: @WideBlade: appending it that way may cause problems, just include it in the parameter with the double quotes (like the example above) and it should work.

Comment: it is still not working. I tried to insert an access token and it still does not work.

Comment: @Ifaour0you were right, apparently I just reached the limit of feed status possible on my test user... thanks!